# When can a probability or entropy relation converted to an equivalent conditional statement?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, entropy, mutual-information

For some probability rules such as
$$
   p(y,x) = p(y|x) p(x)
$$
there is a similar version that is conditioned on an extra variable, like this case
$$
   p(y,x|z) = p(y|x,z) p(x|z)
$$

Also for mutual information
$$
  I(X,Y) = H(X) - H(X|Y)
$$
the conditioned version is
$$
  I(X,Y|Z) = H(X|Z) - H(X|Y,Z)
$$

My question: *is it always true* that you can add a "conditioning variable" in this way?

For example, I think this one is not true
$$
  H(X,Y|Z) \le H(X|Z) + H(Y|Z)
$$

Is there any rules for when it can be applied?

I assume this must be basic and fundamentsal, but I do not see it in several textbooks (Bishop, Friedman)